# Getting all list items within a SharePoint site

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-api

Rather than iterating through a `ListCollection` for a `List`, then `ListItemCollection` for a `ListItem`, does the API offer a more efficient way of getting all ListItems for a given site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no easy ways to get all listitems for a given site.

We have to get all the lists in site first, then loop through each list to get all the items.